# Don't Understand Overflow of Thedailyprophet.net

Tags: wordpress, css

I don't understand why the website is overflowing on mobile. I have added the following code, to no avail.

The website is www.thedailyprophet.net - I have looked over multiple solutions and similar articles. I can't seem to zero in on what's going on here and short of hiring a developer, this is my next solution.

Thanks in advance

```
html {
max-width: 100% !Important; }

body {
overflow-x: hidden !Important;
margin: 0px !Important;
padding: 0px !Important;}
```

Comment: HI, and welcome to the site. Please include a [mcve] in the question; you've added some CSS, which is great, but we need to see enough HTML and CSS in the question to reproduce the issue. Otherwise, this question risks going unanswered or getting closed.

Comment: Should I post all the html in the page source? I don't understand what you mean otherwise. I don't know what is causing the issue in HTML/CSS. I know it's an issue on the website but I can not extrapolate the part of the code you are questioning because I don't know what's causing it :(

Comment: Not all the page source; just enough to reproduce the issue. If you're not sure, then you would need to start with the page source, removing sections bit by bit until you get to the least amount of code (the "Minimal" part of MCVE) that can reproduce the issue. A lot of the time, this process will help you find the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, very cool site!!

Ok, you have one minor and one major culprit I can see...

The main `.container` class needs:

```
overflow: hidden
```

I believe this major culprit has to do with the cool animation you have on the titles of pages and posts, where the individual letters of the title make their way to their final resting place where the title can be read. The letters are animated from off the page view to that final spot, and the viewport in mobile is scrolling horizontally because the letters opacity make them visible while they are still outside of the site width. If you add the `overflow: hidden` rule to the container element the scroll bar goes away(almost entirely, keep reading)...

The minor culprit is the menu `.menu-the-daily-prophet-header-menu`. Has margin PLUS the 100% width... take away the margin-left and margin-right and you should be good.

Comment: Dude, you rock! Thank you for the praise on the website. I have spent 100-200 hours on this design and it's making my eyes go cross. Your solution worked.

May I asked how you identified it so I know in the future? I've never used an effect before like I did on this site for the letters and I'm somewhat new to JS. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Inspected the site in device mode, picked a random mobile profile (iPhone 5/6). I scrolled the site all the way to the right where I could just see the right-most edge of the site and extra white space. Then I scrolled down the page hovering over each container and their contained elements in the Elements panel, highlighting their outlines in the viewport. Menu issue was ez to spot that way but only after a couple refreshes I spotted those animated title characters in the blank white space. My hunch was overflow which I confirmed by adding that rule in the inspector and Voila! Happy to help!